# Left joining table to unpivoted version of itself

Tags: t-sql, unpivot

Hi I have the following code, I wanted to ask if it is okay to Left join a table to an unpivoted version of itself as shown in the code below.

```
 with physician_diag as (

   SELECT baseentityid, eventdate,locationid,teamid,average_muac,child_age,child_gender,physician_diagnosis, dignosis_data
   FROM [VITAL_DWH].[vr].[event_physician_visit]   
UNPIVOT  
   (dignosis_data FOR physician_diagnosis  IN   
      (
     well_baby,
severe_pneumonia) )

AS unpvt )
,

final as (

select *, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY baseentityid ORDER BY eventdate) AS rn from (
select distinct 
v.baseentityid, cast(v.eventdate as date) as eventdate, v.locationid, v.teamid,
p.physician_diagnosis, p.dignosis_data,
v.average_muac, v.child_age , v.child_gender 

FROM [VITAL_DWH].[vr].[event_physician_visit] v
left join physician_diagnosis p on p.baseentityid=v.baseentityid and p.eventdate=v.eventdate

 )
```

Can't I achieve the same result without left joining, as is shown below -

```
with physician_diag as (

   SELECT baseentityid, eventdate,locationid,teamid,average_muac,child_age,child_gender,physician_diagnosis, dignosis_data
   FROM [VITAL_DWH].[vr].[event_physician_visit]   
UNPIVOT  
   (dignosis_data FOR physician_diagnosis  IN   
      (
     well_baby,
severe_pneumonia
)  
)

AS unpvt 
),

final as (
-- Final
select *, dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY baseentityid ORDER BY eventdate) AS rn from (
select * from physician_diag  
 
 ) F
```

In the second analysis,

```
select count(distinct baseentityid) from final
```

gives 9104

In the first analysis,

```
select count(distinct baseentityid) from final
```

gives 9107

I was confused as to why there is a difference.

Comment: Why *wouldn't* it be "ok"? What are you *really* asking here?

Comment: I have edited the question to provide more context, thanks, please help

Comment: We can't run your SQL, but you could easily find out by inspecting the results from the CTEs `final` and seeing what 3 extra values you have for `baseentityid`.